# C Global Struct: "error: expected expression before '{' token"

Tags: c, struct

How can I initialize a global struct within a function? My code does not compile with and coughs up the following error:

```
expected expression before ‘{’ token
gameState = {0, *emptyBoard};`
            ^
```

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
typedef struct {
    int turn;
    char board [6][7];
} GameState;

GameState gameState;

int main(void) {
    char emptyBoard[6][7];
    gameState = {0, *emptyBoard};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `main` should simply have `gameState.turn = 0;`. There's no need for `emptyBoard` because the structure already has an array for the board. In fact, you don't have to do anything in `main` because global variables are initialized to 0 by the startup code when the program is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char emptyBoard[6][7];` is not an empty board; it's a board of uninitialized characters. To make an empty board , put `= { 0 };` on the end of the declaration -- although this whole line is pointless if your intention is just to clear `gameState`.

`gameState` is already zero-initialized because it is a global variable, so you do not actually have to write anything in `main` to reinitialize it.

If you wanted to reset it to zero later you could write:

```
gameState = (GameState){0};
```